# Unable to find the element with data-testid in list rendering in react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, vite, vitest

Currently, the project I am developing is **ReactJs - Vite**. I am following the docs for **react-testing-library** to find if the element with `data-testid` attribute is rendered or not.

The **react-testing-library** cannot find the element even though it exists.

### My Test

```js
it('should render option destination', () => {
    render(<Search destinations={[{ id: 1, name: 'Test' }]} />);
    expect(screen.getAllByTestId('option-search-destination')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

### My Component

```js
...
<Select
  className="search-form__item__field"
  allowClear
  bordered={false}
  style={{ border: 'none' }}
  placeholder={t('search.destination.place_holder')}
  showArrow>
  <OptGroup label="All destinations">
    {destinations &&
      destinations.map((item, index) => (
        <>
          <Option
            key={index}
            value={item.id}
            data-testid="option-search-destination">
            {item.name}
          </Option>
        </>
      ))}
  </OptGroup>
</Select>
...
```

### Test Error

`TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="option-search-destination"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the component you are trying to test is a select. By default, the Select's menu will be closed so the options are not rendered and react-testing-library can't find the options of the select component.

In order for you to be able to target them you need to open the menu of the select component. Assuming it is done by clicking on it, you can either use react testing library's native `fireEvent`, or alternatively use `userEvent` which is a companion library to react-testing-library which they recommend to use [user-event](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro)

Assuming you are using `userEvent` you will need to target your select and apply a click event on it to open the menu. Then the select menu will open and you will be able to query the options within it.

```
it('should render option destination', () => {
    render(<Search destinations={[{ id: 1, name: 'Test' }]} />);
    const select = screen.getByTestId('my-select');
    userEvent.click(select);

    const options = screen.getAllByTestId('option-search-destination')
    expect(options).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```